# Problem when using CASE function in mysql but getting Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, case

I am using CASE statement in a function in mysql like this:

```
BEGIN
declare Rslt1 decimal(10,2);declare Rslt2 int;declare Rslt3 int;
declare Rslt decimal(10,2);declare Tot decimal(10,2);
set Tot = UnitPrice * OrderQty;
if Calctype = 0 then
 set Rslt1 = Tot;
elseif CalcType=1 then -- Buy X Pay Y
 set Rslt2 = floor((OrderQty/X));
 set Rslt3 = (Orderqty - (RSlt2 * X));
 set Rslt1 = CASE
    WHEN Rslt2 =0 THEN  Tot
    WHEN Rslt2>=1 THEN amntpercent(((Rslt2 * UnitPrice * X),ByAmnt, Dscnt) + (Rslt3 * UnitPrice))
  End;
elseif CalcType = 2 then -- for X Pay Y ( Discount by Amnount or Percentage)
  set RSlt1= amntpercent(Tot,ByAmny,Dscnt);
end if; 

RETURN (Rslt1);
```

but I am getting this error every time.
Any help please

Comment: You have 2 calls for `amntpercent()`. In first call one parameter is provided, in another call - 3 parameters. ???

Comment: You are write that was the problem and is solved now. Really appreciated my dear

Comment: I think that this error message is NOT relative to your function. Show the query which calls the function and produces an error - I think that there is some wrong subquery in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you have wrong ()  in a  WHEN condition
try

```
WHEN Rslt2>=1 THEN amntpercent((Rslt2 * UnitPrice * X),ByAmnt, Dscnt) + (Rslt3 * UnitPrice)
```

Comment: I doubt. If this is the only problem than `ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION amntpercent; expected 3, got 1` must be obtained. There is another problem which is detected previously.

Comment: actually you have a point. but really that solved the problem. May  be as by if condition it didn't step to the function at that time. Thanks for follwoup Akina